# disable a button click with jquery on a slide down div

Tags: jquery, html

so I have a slide down div that reveals a menu, but if you rapidly click the button the results are less than desirable. I would like the button to do nothing until the animation is complete, and likewise on the other end. This is what I have so far

```
$(function () {
    $('#header .exploreExpandBtn a').live( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
        $('.exploreNav').stop(true,true).slideToggle();
    })
})
```

and my html

```
<h2 class="exploreExpandBtn logoBtn"><a class="ir" href="#menu-explore-menu" <strong>Explore</strong></a></h2>

<div class="exploreNav clearfix">
<div class="bgShadow clearfix">
<div class="wrap clearfix">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'global-explore-menu' ) ); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note that you need to add a `>` to your anchor tag: `<a class="ir" href="#menu-explore-menu" <!-- this one: --> ><strong`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, it happened when I was copying the code over.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function () {
    $('#header .exploreExpandBtn a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.exploreNav:not(:animated)').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400, function(){
            $this.parent().toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
});
```

Note that I chose `400` as the duration of the animation as it is the default duration that `slideToggle` is shipped with. Docs: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Use .on rather than .live as a best practices

Comment: @darshanags that worked, pretty well, on the line where I toggleClass 'open' how can I prevent that from toggling until the animation is complete as well?

Comment: @user388069 you could also try removing `.stop(true, true)`. I *think* you won't need it but I didn't want to remove it from the answer as I didn't/don't have a working example to see what happens if I remove it. In theory, you should not need `.stop(true, true)` because of the selector `:not(:animated)`.

Comment: I see. Yea it's totally not needed.

Comment: is it possible to have the toggleclass happen as the same time as the click? or is it just because of the flow of it that it happens that way?

Comment: I thought you wanted the `toggleClass` to happen after the animation was completed. If you would like it to happen as soon as the click event fires, just have it as you had before. @user388069

Comment: Well the toggle and the animation are as one. So I wanted the toggle, and the button click to be disabled until the animation was complete. Sorry for the mis-communication.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to check if the animation is in progress or not

```
var animDone = true;
```

Before animating your div

```
//Set to false before animating
animDone = false;
$('.exploreNav').stop(true,true).slideToggle(500,function(){
    //Then true when animation has been done
    animDone = true;
});
```

In your button click callback or whereever you want, test the variable and return `false` if the animation is in progress :

```
if(!animDone)
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button on click and enable it once the animation is complete.

```
$(function () {
    $('#header .exploreExpandBtn a').live( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var that = this; //to refer to the link in the complete function
        $('.exploreNav').stop(true,true).slideToggle(
                 {complete: function() { $(that).removeAttr('disabled')}
        );
    })
})
```